# Why is my IF statement not executed?? And why does the interval continue to run even when I inserted a clearStatement call

Tags: javascript, jquery

The If statement is not being executed. I dont understand why?

the only way I can clear the interval is if I print the command myself without the any if statements.

```
var number = 0;

function addThis(){
  return number +=1;
}

var mySID = setInterval(addThis, 1000); 

if(number === 10){
  clearInterval(mySID);
  number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is running; it's just not evaluating to true, so the "then" doesn't run. Your `if` statement runs immediately after the call to `setInterval`, so `number` is still 0. It won't be 10 for another 10 seconds, but by then the `if` statement has long since finished.

Comment: so basically I would have to put the if statement in a loop or in the function?